# Service in android 5.0+

Tags: android, service, android-5.0-lollipop

I intended to work like this:
user switches on a feature: let say weather.
now weather data will come from server every 6 hours and will be shown to widget(remoteview), Now user switches off the feature. then widget should not show the weather or even refresh the data every 6 hours.
there are also 3-4 more features like that.
Now i had created a service to get all required data and than i have passed them to remoteview. For starting service i had used this in TimeOut Activity:

```
i = new Intent(TimeOut.this, TimeService.class);
i.setAction("com.example.Weather.Idle");
startService(i);
```

same for stopping service in switch off code:

```
stopService(i)
```

This code was working fine in API <=19. But in Lollipop it crashes at starting or stoping service. 
I searched a lot in SO and also tried code for Binding or unbinding service but didn't help any.
Please help me with some code rather than just links... 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you add the stracktrace please?

Comment: actually its not crashing... but service is not being stopped by stopservice(i). It is running though i switched off.

Comment: Then either your `Intent` that you are passing to `stopService()` is different, or something has called `bindService()`, or something else called `startService()` after you called `stopService()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: what i am doing is... i am having 3-4 feature like weather, screen off, usb charging recognition etc. I am starting same service and in service i have done the logic part for each. Should i create separate service for all?

Comment: "Should i create separate service for all?" -- I have no idea.

Comment: How about using `stopSelf()` in service itself?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I was getting error like service should be explicit and all that crap. can i know the simplest way to start and stop service in android 5.0+

Comment: @Froyo: yup this also not helping... may be i am missing something... Lemme check my code once more.. :)

Comment: "I was getting error like service should be explicit and all that crap" -- that is from `bindService()`, not `startService()`.

Comment: Do you get any good solution? Facing the same problem today.

Comment: @Coroner_Rex give me couple of hours... i will find exact piece of code :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting a service from any activity class

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundService.class);
            startService(intent);
```

Here is service class code

```
   public class BackgroundService extends Service{
   public static Context appContext = null;
   @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
   @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (appContext == null) {
         appContext = getBaseContext();
        }
    Toast.makeText(appContext, "Services Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Add your logic here. You can do some work here using a thread. You can stop  service whenever you want and i hope you will not find any crash.

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks @waheed, but its not getting stopped thats my problem. I know how to start and stop service. But my code is not working in android 5.0 :)

Comment: I have tested this piece of code on android 5+.Its working fine.Please try to figure out exact problem.check your manifest file.Have you registered your service ??

Comment: @waheed: as i said that this was working in API <=19. but somehow service is getting started but not stopping. May be i am missing something. :(

Comment: Read about  START_NOT_STICKY  and  START_STICKY  here

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)

Comment: BTW add try/catch and read proper exception and best of luck.

Comment: @kiturk3 One Important thing is If you have refer my code than what you need to do is, make one intent in Activity like intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackgroundService .class) and use that same intent for starting and stopping the service like startService(intent) and stopService(intent)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue with Service in 5.0. This is probably not the correct answer, but it works. You could try. I use `EventBus` to communicate with my services. So when I want to stop the service I'd send,

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new ServiceEvent(ServiceEvent.STOP_SERVICE));
```

In the service,

```
public void onEvent(ServiceEvent event) {
     if (event.getEvent() == ServiceEvent.STOP_SERVICE) {
         methodToStopService();
     }
}

private void methodToStopService() {
   // do some stuff
   stopSelf();
}
```

Make sure you register your service for events.

```
private void registerEventBus() {
    EventBus eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();
    if (!eventBus.isRegistered(this)) {
        eventBus.register(this);
    }
}
```

ServiceEvent class - It's my own class which I use with EventBus.

```
public class ServiceEvent {
    private int event;
    public static final int STOP_SERVICE = -1;

    public ServiceEvent(int event) {
        this.event  = event;
    }

    public int getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
}
```

Comment: looking promising... I will try it soon and let you know. Ty :)

Comment: `ServiceEvent` is a POJO class that I use with EventBus. I apologize for the naming confusion. It might seem like it's part of SDK.

Comment: EventBus is also from POJO??

Comment: No. It's a library for communicating between anything and everything. really helpful. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: not working... it clashing with default library i am using. It shows error in my @Nullable interface i have used. :(

Comment: You could try changing the class name from `ServiceEevnt` to something else. I kept that name for example